# How to CAST/REPLACE NESTED table to change from FLOAT to NUMERIC

Tags: google-bigquery

Problem: I have nested table but now I need to change format some of the columns from FLOAT to NUMERIC, what is the best approach for this issue?

This is what I have tried (the best idea so far)

```
SELECT * 
REPLACE(ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT CAST(OL.VAT AS NUMERIC) FROM UNNEST(OrderLines) OL) AS VAT)
```

But this still does not work, as it just creates a field  - `VAT._field_1`

OR it can be done like this: but it will replace the value, not in the nested table

```
SELECT D.*
REPLACE(CAST(UOL.VAT AS NUMERIC) AS VAT)
FROM D, UNNEST(OrderLines) AS UOL
```

Answer (score 1):

you could directly do alias inside `select as struct`

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(OrderLines),
ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT CAST(OL.VAT AS NUMERIC) AS VAT FROM UNNEST(OrderLines) OL) AS OrderLines
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is the answer

```
SELECT * REPLACE(ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(CAST(VATAS NUMERIC) AS VAT) FROM UNNEST(OrderLines) ol) AS OrderLines)
FROM A
```